# access body in react component to use scrollspy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a react based web app using some html/css styles from one of the free "flat file" templates provided by bootstrap.

the template uses scrollspy to change the correct menu item hover colour to the section the user has scrolled to.

This effect is achieved using this code in one of the javascript files

```
 $('body').scrollspy({
    target: '#nameHere'
  });
```

in my react component, I am trying to do this

```
document.body.scrollspy({ target: '#nameHere' })
```

but when I run the application I am getting a "document.body.scrollspy is not a function" error.

Is there something painfully obvious I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a few ways to get this working.

A more robust way is to use the React Scroll component mentioned by Valentin above, but this involves taking a dependency on another module and because of some other stuff in my situation I wasn't able to get this working.

A quicker, more hacky way is to add

```
data-spy="scroll" data-target="#namehere" data-offset="56"
```

to the body tag of index.html

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I think, the problem is that the `document.body` element has no property `scrollspy`.

Comment: which would make sense. Is there a clean way to achieve what the jQuery code is doing in a react component, or is the best way to used a third party package? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Yes, maybe you should use immediately _react_ library. I recommend you [React Scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll)